# NoSuchWindowException - Selenium 3.4.0 - IE 11

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver, selenium3

I have launched IE 11 browser,

I have navigated to a initial URL --> done mouse over and clicked a link --> it redirects to another page.

In that page, I have to click a button, but it is throwing an exception

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window

but the windows still available on screen.

This is my code

WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/header/nav/ul/li[2]/a"));

```
    Actions a = new Actions(driver);
    a.moveToElement(e).build().perform();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu-item-35']/a")).click();



  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

// Exception is occurs after this, but when I delete the below code, the test case passes

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='default_products_page_container']/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/span/input")).click();
```

This is the URL of the page: http://store.demoqa.com/

Comment: "it redirects to another page." is this a new browser tab?

Comment: Nope, it's same tab and window

Comment: is there any iframe?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this is a race-condition error. I had those cases myself where I could actually see a window, but Selenium still said it wasn't there.

Have you tried setting the sleep time to a higher value?

You could also try to put a expect-wait-condition before clicking your element.

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DRIVER, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='default_products_page_container']/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/span/input"))
```

Comment: I have done it, but is not useful. This might be related to browser configurations

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution to your Question:

A few words about the solution:

1. The `xpath` `html/body/div[2]/div/div/header/nav/ul/li[2]/a` looks petty vulnerable to me use `linkText` locator.
2. Once you use `Action` Class to `build().perform()`, induce a bit of `wait` before locating another element.
3. Instead of `xpath` locator of `//*[@id='menu-item-35']/a` element, use `linkText` locator.
4. Again the `xpath` `//*[@id='default_products_page_container']/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/span/input` looks petty vulnerable to me use a logical unique`xpath`.
5. Here is your own working code block with some simple tweaks in it:

   ```
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Product Category"));
   Actions a = new Actions(driver);
   a.moveToElement(e).build().perform();
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("iMacs")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Buy']")).click();
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: What do you mean by `its not working` ? Can you show the error stacktrace? Are you able to launch the IE Browser? Does it opens the URL?